# How can I nest viewports with the new Angular router?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-new-router

I have the new Angular router (Angular 1.4) working for the unnested routes and viewports.  I cannot get it to work when a nested component has a viewport of its own.  I've read through all the tutorials I could find and none of them discuss nesting.  I'm aware of parallel viewports but that's not what I'm looking for.

Here is what I have.

https://gist.github.com/guyjacks/b15a22d84b804af5d321

-- error --
https://gist.github.com/guyjacks/a0b3ecda9787692a070e

-- here is the current answer --

It appears that child components are broken in the new Angular router.

https://github.com/angular/router/issues/117

I'll leave this question unanswered until it has an answer.

Comment: I think this will not be fixed : https://github.com/angular/router/pull/360/files

Comment: Post your comment as the answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will not be fixed sadly : https://github.com/angular/router/pull/360/files

You'll have to wait for Angular 2